# I cannot find my app on Google Play with app name. I can find using package name

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded an app on Google Play "First Steps" two days back. When I try to find the app on Google Play using the name, I cannot find it. The package name is com.systology.firststeps. Using "systology", I am able to find it.

I gave the app name properly in Google Console. Also, in description, I have put the app name.

Can someone help in telling me what am I missing on?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As you have given the name of your application `First Steps` so the google will always look for the first word to search for and will give you the result according to the first word of your application which matches the most of the application's on the playstore.

If you want to get the exact result of your application on play store you will have write `First Step Systology` then you will get your application only.

Check out https://play.google.com/store/search?q=First%20Steps%20systology&c=apps

Comment: can i modify something in manifest, so that google matches complete name. As google says that the match starts with the manifest file. So, is there anything I can do in manifest file?

Comment: What name you have given in your `<application  android:label="@string/app_name">` string ?

Comment: there I have given it correctly - "First Steps".  android:label="First Steps"

Comment: You will have to think some different name as in your name the word "First" comes so as user will search for the app it always return get the result of the apps whichever contains the word "first" So your application will not be uniquely identified. :)

Comment: The exact result only comes when you will write `First Steps systology` in search. You can get the scenario how the searching is done on play store.